# Image going to random positions: Trying to loop

Tags: javascript

I made my image go to random positions on load but I want it to go to random positions in a loop every, let's say 2 seconds. How would I loop it? All the js tutorials on looping show conditions and stuff. I just want it to go every 2s. (If you run the snippet, keep pressing run and it will go to a different position.)

```js
function getRandomPosition(element) {
  var x = document.body.offsetHeight - element.clientHeight;
  var y = document.body.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
  return [randomX, randomY];
}
window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
  img.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "https://s.cdpn.io/profiles/user/4052743/80.jpg?1580237522"
  );
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  var xy = getRandomPosition(img);
  img.style.top = xy[0] + "px";
  img.style.left = xy[1] + "px";
};
```

```css
img {
  border: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: I'll try to get that working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `setInterval`

```js
function getRandomPosition(element) {
  var x = document.body.offsetHeight - element.clientHeight;
  var y = document.body.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
  return [randomX, randomY];
}
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
img.setAttribute("src","https://s.cdpn.io/profiles/user/4052743/80.jpg?1580237522");
function moveImg(){
  var xy = getRandomPosition(img);
  img.style.top = xy[0] + "px";
  img.style.left = xy[1] + "px";
}
window.onload = function() {

  document.body.appendChild(img);
  setInterval(moveImg, 2000);

};
```

```css
img {
  border: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  }
```